# Hardhat can't find the mint function

Tags: erc-20, testing, hardhat

I'm using hardhat as a framework to develop my smartcontracts. So far it's been great, but im clueless as to why I can't call the mint function from my tests. Here's the error message:

```
Token.connect(...).mint is not a function
```

Here's a skinned down version of my TESTing code:

```
describe("Token contract", function () {
    let TokenContract;
    let Token;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        TokenContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
        [owner, alice, bob, carol, fakeRouter] = await ethers.getSigners();
        Token = await Contract.deploy(); //sender is by default owner/first address
     });
    it('onlyOwner modifier', async () => {
        await expect(Token.connect(alice).mint(bob.address, 
        10)).to.be.revertedWith('operator: caller is not the operator')
    });
```

Here is the mint function residing in my smartcontract code:

```
/// @notice Creates `_amount` token to `_to`. Must only be called by the owner(MasterChef).
function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
    _mint(_to, _amount);
    _moveDelegates(address(0), _delegates[_to], _amount);
}
```

Anybody has an idea of what's going on?

Comment: What's `Contract.deploy()`? There's no definition of `Contract` in your snippet.

Answer (score 3):

This was already answered in Hardhat's discord, but in case anyone ends up here...

The problem is that the `mint` function was overloaded. That is, the contract had two implementations of that function with different signatures:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  function mint(uint amount) public { ... }
  function mint(uint amount, address to) public { ... }
}
```

When this happens, you need to use the full signature in the ethers.js contract as the name of the function:

```js
await foo['mint(uint)'](123)

// or
await foo['mint(uint,address)'](123, "0x123...")
```